# Do all primitive types implement the Copy trait?

Tags: rust

Do all [primitive types in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/primitive-types.html) implement the `Copy` trait?

It would be interesting to know, as surely such knowledge is part of a thorough learning of a new programming language.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We can use the compiler to prove if something implements `Copy`. Using [the list of primitives from *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/primitive-types.html):

```
fn is_copy<T: Copy>() {}

fn main() {
    is_copy::<bool>();
    is_copy::<char>();
    is_copy::<i8>();
    is_copy::<i16>();
    is_copy::<i32>();
    is_copy::<i64>();
    is_copy::<u8>();
    is_copy::<u16>();
    is_copy::<u32>();
    is_copy::<u64>();
    is_copy::<isize>();
    is_copy::<usize>();
    is_copy::<f32>();
    is_copy::<f64>();
    is_copy::<fn()>();
}
```

There are a few other types I'd consider "primitive":

- Immutable references (`&T`)
- Mutable references (`&mut T`)
- Raw pointers (`*const T` / `*mut T`)

Immutable references always implement `Copy`, mutable references never implement `Copy`, and raw pointers always implement `Copy`:

```
// OK
is_copy::<&String>();
is_copy::<*const String>();
is_copy::<*mut String>();
// Not OK
is_copy::<&mut i32>();
```

There are a few other types from the book's list:

- Tuples
- Arrays

These types can contain many types; they are parameterized over a generic. They are only `Copy` if all the contained values are `Copy`:

```
// OK
is_copy::<[i32; 1]>();
is_copy::<(i32, i32)>();
// Not OK
is_copy::<[Vec<i32>; 1]>();
is_copy::<(Vec<i32>, Vec<i32>)>();
```

- Slices

Slices are doubly special. The slice type itself (`[T]`) and string slices (`str`) are *unsized* types. It's very rare to see them without an indirection of some kind, often a reference (`&[T]` / `&str`). The unsized values cannot exist by themselves. The version behind a reference behaves like references do.

```
// OK
is_copy::<&str>();
is_copy::<&[i32]>();
// Not OK
is_copy::<str>();
is_copy::<[i32]>();
```

And as always, the [documentation for a trait lists everything that implements that trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). (Except when there are [bugs in the documentation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25893)).

Comment: I don't see primitive types (e.g. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html) listed in https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html, am I missing something?

Comment: @ArtemGr guh, I really thought that had been fixed by now. I linked to the issue for that.

Comment: But slices (those of the form `&[T]`, not the plain unsized `[T]`), are just references, thus they are always `Copy`. I mean, your last example, once you add a type for the `Vec` generic) actually works: `is_copy(&[Vec::<u8>::new()][..]);`.

Comment: @rodrigo odd, wonder how I missed that. I've rectified that and added a section about references.

Comment: @Shepmaster Typo here: "Immutable references always implement Copy, immutable references never implement Copy" :)