# Do tuples implement `Copy`?

Tags: rust, tuples

In the Rust Book, Chapter 18, they give an example of a tuple in pattern matching.

```
fn print_coordinates(&(x, y): &(i32, i32)) {
    println!("Current location: ({}, {})", x, y);
}

fn main() {
    let point = (3, 5);
    print_coordinates(&point);   // point passed as reference
}
```

Out of curiosity, I tried without passing as a reference like this.

```
fn print_coordinates((x, y): (i32, i32)) {
    println!("Current location: ({}, {})", x, y);
}

fn main() {
    let point = (3, 5);
    print_coordinates(point);   // point passed as value
    print_coordinates(point);   // point is still valid here
}
```

It compiles and prints out the coordinates 2 times.

Can tuples be passed into functions just like other primitive data types (numbers, booleans, etc.)?

Comment: Highly relevant: [Do all primitive types implement the Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41413336/155423)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes; according to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html#trait-implementations-1), this is true for tuples of arity 12 or less:

> If every type inside a tuple implements one of the following traits, then a tuple itself also implements it.
>
> - [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html)
> - [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)
> - [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html)
> - [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html)
> - [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html)
> - [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html)
> - [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html)
> - [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html)
> - [`Hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html)
>
> Due to a temporary restriction in Rust's type system, these traits are only implemented on tuples of arity 12 or less. In the future, this may change.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: If the arity is above 12, your tuple is probably pretty bulky, e.g. `i128` of size 12 already takes 192 bytes, so it indeed doesn't make sense to try to copy a tuple such large (not to mention that there shouldn't be such enormous tuples in the first place; use an array instead)