# Why is assigning an integer value from a vector to another variable allowed in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```rust
fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];

    let mut largest = number_list[0];

    for number in number_list {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number;
        }
    }

    println!("The largest number is {}", largest);
    assert_eq!(largest, 100);
}
```

Shouldn't the ownership of first element in the array be given to largest and hence it shouldn't be usable in loop?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Do all primitive types implement the Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41413336/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`number_list` is a list of integers, and integers implement the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait, which means that they are never moved, but are copied instead. For this reason the array keeps ownership of its elements, and `largest` and `number` get copies of these elements.

If you try to do the same with a non-copy type, then you get an error:

```
struct WrappedInt(i32);

fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| WrappedInt(x))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let mut largest = number_list[0];

    for number in number_list {
        if number.0 > largest.0 {
            largest = number;
        }
    }

    println!("The largest number is {}", largest.0);
    assert_eq!(largest.0, 100);
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f064ad491af1c754c275c51178caa4b2)

gives:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<WrappedInt>`
 --> src/main.rs:9:23
  |
9 |     let mut largest = number_list[0];
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                       |
  |                       move occurs because value has type `WrappedInt`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |                       help: consider borrowing here: `&number_list[0]`
```