# What happens when you clone a `&str`?

Tags: rust

What happens when you clone a `&str`?

Is the cloned `&str` pointing to the same place as clonee `&str` or is it something?

Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [Do all primitive types implement the Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41413336/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Very useful answer. So it falls under the Copy trait rather than the Cloning trait?

Comment: Copy is a bitwise copy, Clone is a method to actually clone data in a smart way. You can have Clone without Copy, but not vice versa. Please see [the `Copy` docs page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html).

Comment: A rite of passage of Rust is understanding that `&T` is `Copy` and `&mut T` is not... I'll let you think about why ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cloning a `&str` is the same as cloning any `&T`; it just copies the reference.

[`Clone` is implemented for any `&T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#impl-Clone-for-%26T). It literally just [returns itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/clone.rs.html#233) since it is [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#impl-Copy-for-%26T).

This is documented [under reference's docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#trait-implementations-1).