# Why borrow persists after clone

Tags: rust, ownership

I can't understand why I am getting this error below:
`

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
7 |     let char_h = s.get(0..0).unwrap().clone();
  |                  ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
8 |     s.replace_range(0..0, "h");
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
9 |     println!("char before {char_h} string after {}", s);
  |                            ------ immutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `q_line_out_of_scope` due to previous error
```

`In the code:`

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("Hello World!!");
    try_changes(&mut s);
}

fn try_changes(s: &mut String) {
    let char_h = s.get(0..0).unwrap().clone();
    s.replace_range(0..0, "h");
    println!("char before {char_h} string after {}", s);
}
```

`

I understand that I borrowed the 's' in line 7 'unwrap', but after borrow it I used clone and have no more references to the borrowed value 's'. So I would like to know why rust don't "drop" the borrow in this case, and a solution on how I could perform this feature (modify a string and have the old string version in some variable).
Thanks.

I have tried to use 'as_ref' but things are becoming more complex and I think I am missing something, so I am trying to understand that so I can procced with rust studying.

Comment: `char_h` is a `&str`. You want `let char_h = s.get(0..0).unwrap().to_string();` to make a `String` from the sliced `&str`.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki Since `char_h` is only used to print out, it is more ideomatic to get `char_h` as a character instead of a `String` with `s.chars().nth(0).unwrap();`.

Comment: @Kaplan Right, I didn't notice that the intention was to get a single character instead of a slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you probably want `0..1` instead of `0..0`. In Rust, and most other programming languages, range definitions are inclusive on the lower end and exclusive on the upper end.

Next, `s.get(0.11).unwrap()` will be of type `&str`, i.e., a string slice. *Cloning* that will just copy the reference. See here: [What happens when you clone a `&str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729718/what-happens-when-you-clone-a-str)

And because of that, cloning won't "release" the borrow. Instead, you'll need to create a new, *owned* string, which would be done via `to_string()`.

See here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ad9ccf4c23669a77b84c1615501afde

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("Hello World!!");
    try_changes(&mut s);
}

fn try_changes(s: &mut String) {
    let char_h = s.get(0..1).unwrap().to_string();
    s.replace_range(0..1, "h");
    println!("char before {} string after {}", char_h, s);
}
```